# pasword_hash($password) is null

Tags: php, password-hash

I have an problem with the pasword_hash function in PHP.

The following Snippet is in use:

```
// Passwort darf nicht leer sein
if (empty($password)) {
    echo "Dieses Feld darf nicht leer sein!";
    $error = true;
}

$passw = password_hash($password);
// Begin der Registrierung
if (!$error) {
    $registerService = new RegisterService();
    try {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($passw);
        echo "</pre>";
        die();
        $session = $registerService->insertRegisteredUser($username, $password);
        echo json_encode(array("success" => 1));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => 0));
    }
}
```

The output of the vardump is null. The password string ist definitve not empty or null. I  dont understand why the function returns null. I use the same function in my login logic, without any problems.

Response of the PHP:

```
<pre><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>/var/www/lernapp/src/register.php:31:</small><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre></pre>
```

Comment: You need to specified an algo for the password_hash, take a look to the documentation : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. I thought that the second param is the salt. And salt is deprecated since PHP 5.x 

Now it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should* be getting an exception reported. Given that you are not I assume you have all exception reporting disabled.

https://3v4l.org/4S1Bu#v8.1.10

password_hash() requires 2 parameters, the thing you want to hash and an algorithm you want to use.

https://3v4l.org/D662K#v8.1.10

Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I also wonder about getting no exception. This I have to check. 

I thought that the second param is the salt. I have read about the salt that this ist deprecated since PHP 5.x 

Now it's clear that I have to set the algo param. But I wonder about. The PASSWORD_DEFAULT should be set by default whe nothing is set. This would mak it a bit better to handle for newbies like me.

Comment: PASSWORD_DEFAULT can change over time because its what PHP sees as the best possible option. You can check what your version of php currently is by echo'ing out PASSWORD_DEFAULT.